# Select all folders with Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

How can I create a custom Automator command to simply select all folders within a folder?

If I runned the action it would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLe3n.png).

Thanks!
Nicolas

Comment: With an `Run AppleScript` action.

Comment: Thanks, and what AppleScript would it be?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any code, I never wrote an AppleScript so I wouldn't know where to begin :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

- `Get Folder Contents` (this will get all items in the given input folder)
- `Filter Finder Items`

  - and set `Kind is Folder`

For testing add `Reveal Finder Items` at the end. Screenshot:

[image]

The result will be the list of folders in the given input folder. This is simple but slow solution. (The `Get Folder Contents` action is **very** slow.

---

The fast solution could be written using some scripting. Actions:

- `Run Shell Script` (set the `Pass Input: as arguments`) and add the following script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    find "$f" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print
done
```

The result is as above, just much-much faster.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the shell script does the job perfectly and indeed much quicker than the finder actions. Thanks again!

Comment: @NicolasDeslé Enjoy it. Also, you could read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AppleScript you can add to a "Run AppleScript action" In Automator

```
set theFolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder" to select every folder of theFolder
```

Comment: After `set theFolder to (choose folder)` all you need is: `tell application "Finder" to select every folder of theFolder`